# Can I use Oauth with MS Dynamics integrate it to my web application

Tags: azure, oauth, dynamics-crm, azure-web-app-service

We are an ISV and we are building a web application and a managed solution for Dynamics CRM. We want MS Dynamics users to be able to access our web application by using Oauth authentication. Our web application does not need to connect to Dynamics; we only want to restrict the use of this application to Dynamics users.

The problem I am facing is as follows: what CRM Root service do I use as I want to support all Dynamics users from all domains  in our web application.

We have set up our client id etc in Azure. But we want to make user that the user is a user of dynamics CRM and we want to get the CRM domain for the user and make sure that domain is registered with us.

```
// TODO Substitute your correct CRM root service address,
// what CRM Root service do I use as I want to support all 
string resource = "https://<which domain to use>.crm.dynamics.com";  

// TODO Substitute your app registration values that can be obtained after you
// register the app in Active Directory on the Microsoft Azure portal.
string clientId = "<we have this>";
string redirectUrl = "http://localhost/SdkSample";
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically everything you need is covered by Discovery service:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607485.aspx

The URL looks like that (you can check it in your CRM->Customizations->Developer Resources):
"https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/api/discovery/v8.1/"
Basically when you call
"https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/api/discovery/v8.1/Instances"
So it does not matter in which organizations the users resides, this is a commond address for all your CRM instances.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So we are setting up our application on Azure AD. After the user authentication, Azure will redirect the user to our application with the oauth token. What steps to take to invoke this API ? When we register the application with Azure, we have to specify all permissions we shall need: what permissions do we need to invoke the discovery  API